# Android Background execution not allowed on Oreo (8.) for intent android.intent.action.EVENT_REMINDER

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an app which has registered BroadcastReceiver which listens for intents android.intent.action.EVENT_REMINDER. From Oreo it doesnt work at all, until you add app as an exception to energy saving.

But that is in my opinion bug in android, because they explicitely say in documentation:

> As part of the Android 8.0 (API level 26) Background Execution Limits,
>   apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register
>   broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest.
>   However, several broadcasts are currently exempted from these
>   limitations

And ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER is in the list!

So if it has an exception, why am I not receiving broadcast, until I whitelist my app to energy optimizations? This should not be necessary, yet it is from Oreo.

Am I doing anything wrong? My manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".services.MyReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EVENT_REMINDER" />
        <data android:scheme="content" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Works perfectly fine pre-Oreo. After Oreo ONLY if I add app as an exception to battery saving.

Comment: What is the solution?  I am seeing the same warning.

Comment: I havent find any solution :( I hate when Google doesnt even follow their own documentation...So far only solution is to whitelist app (add as an exception), so I am displaying big warning in my app.